# how do I use mod_rewrite for just one file?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod-rewrite for just one file instance:

www.domain.com/contact

to pull from www.domain.com/contact.php

I used a rewrite rule for all files that look like a directory to do this initially but it messed up some diretory redirects I created so in the short-term, I'd rather just do it for a specific file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
```

This will redirect requests of the URL path `/contact` internally to `/contact.php`. If you don’t want to use this rule in a .htaccess file, prepend the pattern with a `/` → `^/contact$`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to something like that:

```
RewriteRule ^/contact.php$ url_to_redirect/contact.php [P,QSA]
```

And just in case you have more available information [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule).

Comment: This will not do what the OP asked.  She doesn't want to redirect across domains.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# make sure http://domain.com redirects to http://www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect from /contact to /contact.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [R=301,L]
```